# Core Plot and 365 days. Padding issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, plot, padding, core-plot

I have a trouble with Core Plot 1.0 for iOS (Yes, i can't update it now)

- My datasource return ~365 values for one year.
- If i draw graph with 30 values is offset from the axis Y, for example:  | -line here- |
- If i draw all the values, then stick to the graph the Y-axis, for example:  |-line here-|

How i can add padding to Plot, not Graph or PlotArea ?

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the `xRange` of the plot space. The `-expandRangeByFactor:` method will enlarge the range, keeping the current range centered. If you start with a range that covers the data (e.g., after calling `-scaleToFitPlots:`), you'll end up with a gap on either side of the data next to edges of the plot area.

Comment: `[xRangeMutable setLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(xRangeMutable.locationDouble - 4.0)]; [xRangeMutable setLength:CPTDecimalFromDouble(xRangeMutable.lengthDouble + 8.0)];` After this code xRange is best, but selection view position is incorrect :(

Comment: It's mean selection view can move behind plot borders... [Correct](https://nas.idev.pro/owncloud/index.php/s/BgiRRHSAAfLieOI) / [Incorrect](https://nas.idev.pro/owncloud/index.php/s/qL2S4I623A9QvXb)

Comment: How are you positioning the selection view? If you use a plot space annotation, it will be tied to data coordinates and will move when the plot ranges change.

Comment: I catch event over this method: `- (BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceUpEvent:(CPTNativeEvent *)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
 if (NO == self.isDragging && NO == self.shouldIgnoreTouchUpEvent)
 {
  [self plotSpace:space handleDeviceEvent:event atPoint:point];
 }
 else
 {
  self.isDragging = NO;
  self.shouldIgnoreTouchUpEvent = NO;
 }
 
 return NO;
}`. This function: `[self plotSpace:space handleDeviceEvent:event atPoint:point];`